# Unlock encrypted partition and read data

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, mount, hard-drive, encryption

I have 2 hard disks- 128GB SSD, and 1TB.
My system drive ( 128gb ssd) encrypted (during Ubuntu 18 installation).
I tried to cancel the encryption, but it's failed, and my second disk (1TB) encrypted to, and my system can't boot. I used the  `fsck`  to fix- and now it's can only give me a grub command-line. 
I have the password of both (the same). 
I have used live ubuntu, and here the results:

[image: first drive]

I have unlocked the 1TB- but I cant mount it and get access to my data.

[image: try to mount]

and get an error:

```
mount /dev/sda4 /mnt
mount: /mnt: unknown filesystem type 'crypto_LUKS'
```

How can I get my data back?

Second  128GB SSD drive is locked. I have the password- when I boot the system (before braked) I can unlock the 128 drive with the same password.
But now  I can't unlock the drive- here is the error:

[image: Can't unlock 128GB SSD]

Some pictures of my disks system:

[image: 1TB drive]

[image: 128GB SSD drive]

I have installed win8 on 50GB partition, and try to use `librecrypt` and `Ext2Read`. Both cannot help me.

I'd appreciate help

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ lsblk -o NAME,SIZE,FSTYPE,TYPE,MOUNTPOINT /dev/sda
NAME     SIZE FSTYPE      TYPE MOUNTPOINT

sda    931.5G             disk 
├─sda1    62M vfat        part 
├─sda2   128M             part 
├─sda3  46.5G ntfs        part 
└─sda4 884.9G crypto_LUKS part 
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ lsblk -o NAME,SIZE,FSTYPE,TYPE,MOUNTPOINT /dev/sdb
NAME     SIZE FSTYPE      TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sdb    119.2G             disk 
├─sdb1   512M vfat        part 
├─sdb2   732M ext4        part 
└─sdb3   118G crypto_LUKS part
```

Comment: What is the output of `lsblk /dev/sda` and `lsblk /dev/sdb`?

Comment: What is the output of  `lsblk -o NAME,SIZE,FSTYPE,TYPE,MOUNTPOINT /dev/sd?`   ?

Comment: #Ravexina # abu_bua added